# Flagging rows in a Group By manner

Tags: r

I want to distiguish between 3 cases:

```
1 - Events A and B happened at the same session ("ID") - "flag 1".
2 - Events B happened without A - "flag 2".
3 - Else - "flag 0".
```

For example:

```
ID   EVENT
1      A
1      B
2      D
2      E
2      C
3      B
4      A
```

I'd like to get:

```
ID   FLAG 
1      1
2      0
3      2
4      0
```

Comment: Not clear to me. Why `ID` 1 is 1 and `ID` 3 is 2 ?

Comment: I edited it so it'll be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use `dplyr::case_when` to summaries values for IDs. In this case use of `any` and `all` will help in deciding if summarise data contains both `A` and `B` or only `B`. The solution will be as:

```
library(dplyr) 
# In addition, "plyr" shouldn't be brought to the session, otherwise
# it will return one line   

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(FLAG = case_when(
    any(EVENT == "A") & any(EVENT == "B") ~ 1,
    all(EVENT == "B")                     ~ 2,
    TRUE                                  ~ 0
  )) %>% as.data.frame()

#   ID FLAG
# 1  1    1
# 2  2    0
# 3  3    2
# 4  4    0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID   EVENT
1      A
1      B
2      D
2      c
3      B
4      A",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: `2 - Events B happened without A - "flag 2".` you might want to change your second condition.

Comment: I get:
``FLAG`` ``\n``
``1    1`` for your example (and my code)

Comment: @InterruptedException May be you can try restarting your `RStudio`. Also, which version of `dplyr` is installed at your end?

Comment: @RonakShah There is no `Event B` for `ID = 2`. Hence `FLAG` should be `0`. Am I correct?

Comment: @MKR :
``RStudio`` ``Version 1.1.453`` and ``dplyr_0.7.5``

Comment: @MKR - I opened a new session without  "plyr" and it worked (though I was explicitly referencing the dplyr function)  .I edited your answer, addeding this  comment.